# Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value (firebase, swift)

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'd like to get the teamID from firebase, but the above error will occur.
This is what happens when the user first registers (registration ⇨ login set).
When logging for the second time or later, you can obtain team ID from firebase.
I do not know why it happens at first registration.
Could you tell me how to solve it?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        circleButton = Circle()

        if arr != nil {
            self.arr = []
            self.dataNameFromFireStore = [Any]()
            self.dataTimeFromFirestore = [Any]()
            self.dataTitleFromFireStore = [Any]()
            self.submitDocumentIdArr = [Any]()

            self.selectedNum = 1

            userTable.delegate = self
            userTable.dataSource = self
            userTable.register(UINib(nibName: "userTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "cellName")

            self.db.collection("users").document(self.fireAuthUID).addSnapshotListener { (snapshot3, error) in
                guard let document3 = snapshot3 else {
                    print("erorr2 \(String(describing: error))")
                    return
                }
                let data = document3.data()

                self.teamIDFromFirebase = (data!["teamID"] as? String)! ←　An error occurred here！！！！！！！！！！

                self.db.collection("diary").document(self.teamIDFromFirebase).collection("diaries").whereField("submit", isEqualTo: true).getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
                    if let err = err {
                        print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
                    } else {
                        var i = 0
                        for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                            self.timelineDocumentIdArr.append(document.documentID)

                            let documentData = document.data()
                            self.dataTitleFromFireStore.append((documentData["今日のタイトル"] as? String)!)
                            self.dataTimeFromFirestore.append((documentData["time"] as? String)!)
                            self.dataNameFromFireStore.append((documentData["userName"] as? String)!)
                            self.arr.append(CellData(image: UIImage(named: "weight")!, name: self.dataNameFromFireStore[i] as! String, time: self.dataTimeFromFirestore[i] as! String, title: self.dataTitleFromFireStore[i] as! String))
                            print(self.arr)

                            i += 1

                        }
                        self.userTable.reloadData()
                        print("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!")
                        print(self.timelineDocumentIdArr)
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            return arr = [CellData(image: UIImage(named: "")!, name: "", time: "", title: "")]
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem you are having is that you are force unwrapping the data inside your document3 and also your querySnapshot. Hence when there is no data your app will crash... Please try the below code and let me know if it know works!

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    circleButton = Circle()

    if arr != nil {
        self.arr = []
        self.dataNameFromFireStore = [Any]()
        self.dataTimeFromFirestore = [Any]()
        self.dataTitleFromFireStore = [Any]()
        self.submitDocumentIdArr = [Any]()

        self.selectedNum = 1

        userTable.delegate = self
        userTable.dataSource = self
        userTable.register(UINib(nibName: "userTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "cellName")

        self.db.collection("users").document(self.fireAuthUID).addSnapshotListener { (snapshot3, error) in
            guard let document3 = snapshot3 else {
                print("erorr2 \(String(describing: error))")
                return
            }

            guard let data = document3.data() else { return }
            self.teamIDFromFirebase = data["teamID"] as? String ?? ""

            self.db.collection("diary").document(self.teamIDFromFirebase).collection("diaries").whereField("submit", isEqualTo: true).getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
                if let err = err {
                    print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
                } else {
                    var i = 0
                    guard let querySnapshot = querySnapshot else { return }
                    for document in querySnapshot.documents {
                        self.timelineDocumentIdArr.append(document.documentID)

                        let documentData = document.data()
                        self.dataTitleFromFireStore.append(documentData["今日のタイトル"] as? String ?? "")
                        self.dataTimeFromFirestore.append(documentData["time"] as? String ?? "")
                        self.dataNameFromFireStore.append(documentData["userName"] as? String ?? "")
                        self.arr.append(CellData(image: UIImage(named: "weight")!, name: self.dataNameFromFireStore[i] as? String ?? "", time: self.dataTimeFromFirestore[i] as? String ?? "", title: self.dataTitleFromFireStore[i] as? String ?? ""))
                        print(self.arr)

                        i += 1

                    }
                    self.userTable.reloadData()
                    print("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!")
                    print(self.timelineDocumentIdArr)
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        return arr = [CellData(image: UIImage(named: "")!, name: "", time: "", title: "")]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! ! ! ! !
It worked well! ! ! ! !
Thank you very much!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help! Please remember to upvote the answer and mark it as accepted, thank you!